# Спискоразрушающие функции. Лисп.

Tags: lisp

Здравствуйте!
Задача такая:
необходимо вставить новый элемент в упорядоченный список, сохранив его упорядоченность.
Список сначала неупорядочен. Работать необходимо с одним и тем же списком не создавая новый в процессе сортировки и вставки.

Пока я вообще даже не нашла хорошей информации про спискоразрушающие функции.

Comment: @АннаХатико, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: пока вопрос - какие есть вообще спискоразрушающие функции? материал еще по ним не прочитан, в литературе тоже нигде пока не нашла

Comment: "Задача такая: необходимо вставить новый элемент в упорядоченный список, сохранив его упорядоченность. Список сначала неупорядочен."

Так он упорядочен или неупорядочен?

Comment: неупорядочен

Comment: > вставить новый элемент в упорядоченный список

> Список сначала неупорядочен

Что за фигня?

Comment: В список упорядоченный по возрастанию вставить новый элемент, сохранив упорядоченность.
Оговорка преподавателя: сначала просто вводим список, упорядочиваем его и потом добавляем новый элемент.

Answer (score 3):

Допустим, речь идет о Common Lisp.

Есть макра [`(push item list)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_push.htm), которая заталкивает значение `item` на верх списка `list`. По сути, оно эквивалентно `(setf list (cons item list))`.

Соответственно, чтобы деструктивно вставить элемент в список с нужной позиции нужно взять список после этой позиции, и заменить его, вставив элемент используя `push`.

Правда, есть одна проблема — хвост разумнее всего получать используя [`nthcdr`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nthcdr.htm), а это функция, а не accessor (как `car` или `cdr`), и `setf` так просто его не отдать. Просто пишется вставка *после* позиции — берем `cdr` от `nthcdr` — его можно скормить `push`/`setf`, вот и дело с концами:

```
(defun insert-after (item list index) 
  "Destructively inserts 'item' into 'list' after 'index'."
  (push item (cdr (nthcdr index list))) 
  list)
```

А вот чтобы вставить перед позицией придется чуть хитрее, случай с нулевым `index` обрабатывать надо особо. Получится уже макра, а не функция (т.к. делать из функции `(setf list …)` бессмысленно — область видимости другая, см. пример 8.6.8 по ссылке):

```
(defmacro insert-at (item list index) 
  "Destructively inserts 'item' into 'list' before 'index'."
  `(if (zerop ,index)
       (push ,item ,list)
       (insert-after ,item ,list (1- ,index))))
```

Проверяем:

```
(setf test-list '(a b c d))
(insert-at 'z test-list 0)  => (z a b c d)
(insert-at 'x test-list 5)  => (z a b c d x)
```

Для удаления проще всего, наверное, воспользоваться `setf` — скажем, чтобы удалить первый элемент списка, нужно заменить сам список на `cdr` от него. Чтобы удалить второй — заменить `cdr` на `cddr`. И т.д.

Если понятна логика вставки, то с удалением проблем быть не должно.

Comment: я на XLisp делаю.
И по-моему надо через функции RPLACD , RPLACA  делать..
без макросов.. и т.д.

Comment: Тут много возможных путей решения. Можно и через них, это просто инструменты немного более низкого уровня, чем `push` или `nth`, они работают с cons'ами, а не списками.

С XLisp, увы, не знаком.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте макрос `setf` вместе с `nth`.

```
(defvar *x* '(1 2 3 4))
(nth 3 *x*) ; => 4
(setf (nth 3 *x*) -1)
*x* ; => (1 2 3 -1)
```

Пользуйтесь [оригинальной документацией по Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/Contents.htm), там есть всё.

Comment: И как в этой оригинальной документации найти термин "спискоразрушающие"? 

Термин, как мне кажется, относительно новый, 21-го века.

Оно конечно, проблемы перевода при неустоявшейся русскоязычной терминологии -- проблема старая, но "спискоразрушающие" -- это круто. Функцию применил -- и списка как не бывало. Да ещё и соседние списки могут пострадать.

Comment: Оно там просто называется «destructive». «Спискоразрушающие» это уже попытка склеить два определения («для работы со списками» и «деструктивные»/«разрушающие»/«мутаторы»/…) в одно слово.

Comment: Имелись ввиду функция модифицирующие список, так убого перевели `destructive list modification`.